# script fails to run number of expected times

Tags: bash, for-loop, pid

So I have this shell script that I think should run a given number of times, sleep then resume, and output the results to a log file

```
#!/bin/bash

log=/path/to/file/info.log
a=$(COMMAND1 | cut -d : -f 2)
b=$(COMMAND2 | grep VALUE| cut -c 7,8)

for i in {1..4}
 do
         echo "Test" $i  >> $log
         date >> $log
         echo $a >> $log
         echo "$((-113 + (($b * 2)))) VALUE" >> $log
         sleep 60
 done
```

When I run `ps -ef | grep scriptname.sh` it seems the script does run. Executes once then the PID is gone as if the run has completed.

I have tested the script and know that it is running and capturing the data I want. But I do not understand why its not incrementing and not sure why its ending earlier than expected. Thanks for any input

info.log output sample

```
Test {1..4}
DATE IN UTC
EXPECTED VALUE OF a
EXPECTED VALUE OF b
```

Comment: Btw.: Please fix your shebang.

Comment: Show how to start the script.

Comment: fixed thanks. from script path> ./scriptname.sh &

Comment: Please add content of /path/to/file/info.log to your question (no comment).

Comment: you mean what gets output into the log? that looks like this....never Test 1, Test 2, Test 3....always Test {1..4}...added as edit to original post

Comment: Then you're running your script with `sh` instead of `bash`. Running `sh yourscript` makes it be interpreted as a `sh` script (ignoring the `#!/bin/bash` shebang), so `{1..4}` is just the string `"{1..4}"` instead of expanding to `"1" "2" "3" "4"`.

Comment: Just run your script with `/path/to/yourscript`, not `sh yourscript` (and [don't use `.sh` extensions on executable scripts at all](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), and _especially_ not on things that are bash scripts instead of sh scripts; filename extensions should be used for shell _libraries_, not shell _scripts_).

Comment: Please add output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` and `echo "$-"` to your question.

Comment: As a note -- it's more efficient to put `>>"$log"` immediately after `done` (and thus open the output file just once and keep it open for the whole loop) instead of `>>"$log"` at the end of each command inside the loop (opening it, writing one command's output, closing it, then re-opening it again on the next line with `>>"$log"` on it, as the current code does).